# Remove a specific ItemizedOverlay from Android GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, itemizedoverlay

I did as you told me.I would lie to ask inside the oncreate() should a put something except from
`mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();` ??
 Also, at the start of my mainactivity class, where i declare all the variables, what should i put? I have :

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay0;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay1;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay2;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay3;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay4;
 HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay5;

 GeoPoint point;

 Drawable drawable0;
 Drawable drawable1;
 Drawable drawable2;
 Drawable drawable3;
 Drawable drawable4;
 Drawable drawable5;

 OverlayItem overlayItem5;
 OverlayItem overlayItem0;
 OverlayItem overlayItem1;
 OverlayItem overlayItem2;
 OverlayItem overlayItem3;
 OverlayItem overlayItem4;`
```

Is there a problem to use the same geopoint variable(point) for all the categories of markers?
In order to add the overlay items to each category i did:

```
try { 
    Drawable drawable0 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_default);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay0 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable0, this);
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);    
       for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);          
           double d1 =json.getDouble("longtitude");
           double d2 =json.getDouble("latitude");        

           GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (d2 * 1E6),
                                        (int) (d1 * 1E6));            
           OverlayItem overlayItem0= new OverlayItem((GeoPoint) point, "Center", "Center");  
           itemizedoverlay0.addOverlay(overlayItem0);        
       }//for
       mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay0);    
       mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
       mc.setZoom(7);      
}//try
```

Also the  `mapOverlays.remove(itemizedoverlay0);`   does not work..Thanks!

---

It still doesnt work.. In the rm0() function i think is the problem. I Write:

```
 public void rm0()
  {                
          for(int i=0; i< mapOverlays.size();i++)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in the rm0"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              mapOverlays.remove(overlayItem0);
          }

  }
```

How can i delete the itemizedOverlay0 only?? I have tried itemizedoverlay0.clearOverlay(); too but nothing happens..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing call `populate()` after changing the items in the `ItemizedOverlay`.

Change the methods as per bellow:

```
public void removeOverlay(int item) {
      mOverlays.remove(item);
      populate();
} 

public void clear() {
      mOverlays.clear();
      populate();
}
```

--EDITED--

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay0 = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable0, this);
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        double d1 =json.getDouble("longtitude");
        double d2 =json.getDouble("latitude");
        Drawable drawable0 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_default);
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (d2 * 1E6), (int) (d1 * 1E6));
        OverlayItem overlayItem0= new OverlayItem((GeoPoint) point, "Center", "Center");
        itemizedoverlay0.addOverlay(overlayItem0);
    }
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay0);
    mapView.getController().animateTo(point);
    mc.setZoom(7);
}
```

Regards

Comment: I did that but nothing seems to happen.In the rm0() function what am i supposed to put??

Comment: You also need to move the code that add the `itemezedoverlay0`out of the loop as in my edited answer.

Comment: when i put the mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay0); outside for it doesnt work at all.

Comment: There is one additional line that needs t be moved outside, before the loop. Check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! i did that! but what is the right way to remove it in the rm0()?

Comment: The problem is not with removing, which is fine. The problem is with the way you are adding the `ItemizedOverlay`. Your original code is adding the `ItemizedOvelay`several times to the active overlays. Indeed, it is re-adding the overaly, everytime you add a new `OverlayItem` to it. The correct process is: 1 - create `ItemizedOveraly`; 2- Add all `OverlayItems` (markers) to the `ItemizedOverlay`; 3- Add `ItemizedOverlay` to the list of active map overlays callind `mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay0)`.

Comment: To remove overlay you have two options: 1- call `mapOverlays.remove(itemizedoverlay0)` which removes the `ItemizedOverlay` from the list of active overlays; 2- call `itemizedoverlay0.clear()`, which leaves the `ItemizedOverlay` in the list of active overlays, but without markers.